# Vue.js create menu querying database

Tags: vue.js, axios, vuex, octobercms

based on the following VueSchool tuto https://vueschool.io/courses/vue-router-for-everyone I'm trying to create a Vue app with a menu based on a list of applications found in an October server. I try to replace the static destinations[] by an applications[] filled from the database.

For that I use Axios and Vuex. I'm able to query the data, but I spent many hours trying to get it at the application loading, to create the menu, before the application is displayed...

I have a main.js an App.vue and a MenuApp.vue component for displaying the menu.
My problem is that my getter is always called before my mutation and that my application array is always empty when the menu is creating.

Is there a way to load and init properly all data before displaying my vue.js menu component ???

Or could I reload my menu component after the mutation ?

Thanks for help  ;-)

Comment: hmm if I am not wrong you are using vuex so it should be `reactive`. means it does not matter when data arrives from server. but when data arrived from server vuex should update store and your menu component should display it using vuex store. if its not displaying it then you should check your vuex store and connect it correctly

Comment: Thanks Hardik, I was trying to connect to a getter of all applications, not the state applications. It now work  ;-))

Comment: It's really weird. The display works after compilation, but when I refresh the page, the menu is lost. If I look with DevTools, my vuex store still contains the data...
Do I need to reload my component ?

Comment: hmm i not sure if you store has data then, may be there should some linking errors, as store and component should be in same state always. if store has data your component will never be empty. please check your connection of store -> component. may be you are conditionally updating stuff etc

Comment: Thanks, it seems to work with the add of vuex-persistedstate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a "loading" layout, before load the main layout.
From "loading" layout, use async to load the applications list and all data you want to get before. At the end, just switch to main layout with applications list loaded.

From OctoberCMS side, I don't know how you are made the requests. But, try to use simple routes, calling router controllers, instead of using components. This will made a more direct request, and a better performance on your final project.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm using October routes, they are simpler !
I'll try loading layouts...